# How do you store the current user as a property on a web api model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I am using a web api 2 and creating a message object to save to the database. This message object needs to have the current user stored on it as an application user type.

My code looks like this:

```
        var UserManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal;
        var currentUserName = currentUser.Identity.Name;
        var currentApplicationUser = UserManager.FindByName(currentUserName);

        // I perhaps want to dispose of the user context? 
        // UserManager.Dispose();

        globalMessage.sentBy = currentApplicationUser;
        db.GlobalMessages.Add(globalMessage);
```

The last line is throwing the error: `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`

Is there another way around this. Otherwise, I imagine, I could call an action which gets the current user, redirect to another action from the action with this user as an arg and then perform the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're attaching to your `db` context an  entity (`currentApplicationUser`) that already is attached to another context instance that is alive too, so a solution could be to find the user using the same context, in your case it would be something like:

```
    var UserManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal;
    var currentUserName = currentUser.Identity.Name;
    var currentApplicationUser =db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.UserName==currentUserName);

    globalMessage.sentBy = currentApplicationUser;
    db.GlobalMessages.Add(globalMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will select yours as you got there 3 minutes before me. Good to see that you did it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out:

```
    var currentUser = RequestContext.Principal;
    var currentUserName = currentUser.Identity.Name;
    var sender = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == currentUserName).FirstOrDefault();
    globalMessage.sentBy = sender;
    db.GlobalMessages.Add(globalMessage);
    db.SaveChanges();
```